# I want to integrate the avatar feature just like the snap chat with fully customizable options like shoes etc I have to do it in flutter Application?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want to integrate the 3d avatar just like the snap chat in my flutter mobile application any method to do so ?

i have seen and tried readyplayer.me to integrate but it dont have feature to change the shoes and tshirts separately.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAHnr.png)